# Java library for Pattern mining on time based data

Tags: data-mining, java

We have a number representing volume of posts per minute on numerous subjects. We want to be able to find patterns so that we can predict what the volume of posts will be in the future.

We want the pattern detection process to be automatic (no human interaction required) and we have been wondering if there is any way to automate it. We have been reading about "pattern mining", but we haven't been able to find any java libraries we could start working with.

Are there any Java libraries for Pattern mining on time based data that we could use to automate this pattern mining process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use `SimpleDateFormat` if it is about date parsing? Or, even better, Joda Time? Can you give a sample?

Comment: By "automate" I would write code to do it.  Data mining tends to be very specific to what you are trying to mine and how the data is represented.  Computers don't automagically find patterns like a human would, you need to write code to determine how closely the data fits a model.

Answer (score 2):

You could check my open source Data Mining framework: http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/  (SPMF)

It provides more than 130 algorithms. Several of them are designed to perform time-related data mining tasks such as discovering sequential patterns and sequential rules in a set of sequences.

I don't know if some of them would fit your needs. But you can check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some pretty solid data mining libraries out there for Java. I have used WEKA for classification and association mining (http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). I have also used Mahout for clustering (http://mahout.apache.org/). You do need to know what you are doing beforehand with regards handling your data. 95% of your time will be spent on cleaning out bad data and preprocessing what remains into a format that can be used by those frameworks.

You are a little light on details of your problem. Sounds like you want some sort of alerting system based on the frequency of some set of events in your data. If it is purely based on frequencies (i.e. - something that defies your assumed distribution of events over time) then you probably want to look at a technique call n-gramming. Trying to avoid being esoteric here but you want to use n-grams where n is not a fixed length. It is a technique common used in NLP and if you are familiar with the longest common substring problem, then you should have some idea of how to got about doing it.

Comment: I have given a bit more detail on the problem. I am not sure n-gramming will be able to help us here. Nevertheless, are there any other ideas you could suggest us?

Comment: Okay, what you want to do is build a regression model. I'm not really a regression guy but they are easy enough do if you are using a framework like WEKA. In fact, here is an article about it: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-weka1/index.html. Basically from your standpoint, you want to format your data, feed it into WEKA, persist the regression model that you train, then use that model to do predictions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to do two very different things:
1) text classification (topics)
2) predicting future topics/volume

1) For text classification, any of the standard NLP libraries is ok- GATE, OpenNLP, LingPipe etc. Personally I would use NLTK or just write my own topic classifier as I think the big java libraries are unwieldily and user-unfriendly. Easier to have something lightweight.

You probably need to train your classifier with labeled data- if you have labeled data, good, if not, time to start labeling. The most important thing as always is data quality- how representative is your training data of the data you expect to see? How good are your features (n-grams, word n-grams, etc)?

2) For prediction, there are any number of statistical models you could use. Personally I'd go for a stochastic model, but that's just cause I spent too much time studying those.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) (General Architecture for Text Engineering) a open source infrastructure for text processing , you can use its IDE (Gate Developer) to build text processing components using a comprehensive set of other plugins or if you need to use it on your code you need to embed its jar file into your project .
this tool has a language called JAPE (Java Annotation Patterns Engine) it allows you to recognise regular expressions in annotations on documents (you can annotate the document using gate analyzers or you can develop your own analyzers).